# Newly created express routes return CANNOT GET / on website. Works fine on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Not long ago I moved my website from hostgator to digitalocean. All migration completed successfully. Though I realized that all newly created routes are not working now. It all works well and without errors on localhost:5000. Then I commit the changes to github/push, pull repo to DigitalOcean droplet server. And check the website. The changes are seen and effective but when I go to "/test" it returns "Cannot GET /test".

My app.js:

```
    var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


app.use(express.static("public"));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.set("view engine","ejs");

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/test",function(req,res){
    res.render("test");
});

app.get("/nalog",function(req,res){
    res.render("nalog");
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT,() => console.log("servers started on port"));
```

For instance here "/nalog" is one of many previously created pages and is working fine. "/test" (which i created few mins ago) however returns CAN NOT GET /.

I use ejs for templates. My test.ejs file looks like this:

```
<%- include("partials/header") %>

<h1>Test file</h1>

<%- include("partials/footer") %>
```

I got header:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,500;1,600;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">

    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">

    <title>Website </title>
  </head>
  
  <body> 
      <!-- Top bar -->
    <header>
        <nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
              <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
                  <img src="/imgs/logo.png">
                  <div class="d-inline-block navbar-brand-text">Тоң райондук акимиатынын <br> расмий сайты <span class="badge badge-info">beta</span> </div>
              </a>
  
              <div class="d-flex flex-row order-2 order-sm-3">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
                      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100037324431723" target="_blank" class="nav-link px-2"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="nav-link px-2"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria="Переключение навигационной панели">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
  
              </div>
  
  
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
  
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="/" class="nav-link">Main</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link">Covid</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="/" class="nav-link">Link-3</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link">Link-4</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link">Link-5</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
  
  
        </nav>

    </header>
```

[This is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooeYK.png)

have my test.ejs in views

Comment: I tried but I didn't get any problem.

Comment: Probably you making mistake on Digitalocean. Check your Digitalocean settings.